# How to stop ScalaZ Process created by time.awakeEvery?

Tags: scalaz-stream

I learned that by `scalaz.stream.time.awakeEvery(1.second)` I can create a process that creates an event every one second. Quite obvious. I can then map that process to accomplish some task every second. So far so good.

What if I want to stop this activity? I tried `p.kill.run.run`, where `p` is the process created by `time.awakeEvery(1.second)`, but it doesn't work.

So the code looks like this:

```
implicit val sc = new java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1)
val p = time.awakeEvery(1.second)
p.map(println(_)).run.runAsync {
  // just some printlines
}

Thread.sleep(4000)
println("Killing")
p.kill.run.run
println("Killed")
```

Still, it prints time after printing "Killed" and goes on and on forever.

How can I stop the process, and free the resources (threads) used by it? I found out I can stop it by shutting down the ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor, but isn't there some more elegant way?

Answer (score 1):

You might take a look at the `runAsyncInterruptibly` combinator on `scalaz.concurrent.Task`.  You can pass it an `AtomicBoolean`, which will then cancel execution when set to `true`, or have it return a function that when called will cancel execution.

Using an `AtomicBoolean`:

```
implicit val sc = new java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1)

val cancel = new java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean(false)

val p = time.awakeEvery(1.second)
p.map(println).run.runAsyncInterruptibly(_ => (), cancel)

Thread.sleep(4000)
println("Killing")
cancel.set(true)
println("Killed")
```